# Extract terms of an expression

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a sympy function that extracts all terms of an equation of `Add` , `Mul` and `Div` expressions, as a list or set?

For example:

```
(x**2 +(x-1)*ln(x)+(x+2)/(x-1))
```

I want to get :

```
[x**2,(x+1)*ln(x),(x+2)/(x-1)]
```

same thing with Mul:

```
(x-1)*ln(x) : [(x-1),ln(x)]
```

and Divison:

```
(x+2)/(x-1) : [x+2,x-1]
```

Comment: You can use the AST module.

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras He could use AST, but most probably _should not_. It would be *much easier* to use existing SymPy tools. (by "much easier" i mean a thousand times easier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a sum or product, you can use `expr.args`:

```
In [1]: ((x**2 +(x-1)*ln(x)+(x+2)/(x-1))).args
Out[1]:
⎛ 2  x + 2                ⎞
⎜x , ─────, (x - 1)⋅log(x)⎟
⎝    x - 1                ⎠

In [2]: ((x-1)*ln(x)).args
Out[2]: (x - 1, log(x))
```

For a division, SymPy represents `x/y` as `x*y**-1` (there is no division class, only `Mul` and `Pow`).

```
In [3]: ((x+2)/(x-1)).args
Out[3]:
⎛  1         ⎞
⎜─────, x + 2⎟
⎝x - 1       ⎠
```

However, you can use `fraction` to split it

```
In [4]: fraction((x+2)/(x-1))
Out[4]: (x + 2, x - 1)
```